# MonoGame 3.0.1 Xamarin 5.0.1 Addin Error

Tags: c#, ios, monogame

I am getting the following error when trying to add the MonoGame templates to Xamarin Studio:

[image: [Error](http://imgur.com/0JNHhb6)]

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source from here:

https://github.com/stebyrne04/Monogame_templates

And used the mpack provided and it seems to work now.